How do you calculate how long an iPad is supported? Is this similar to Android?
I am an Android user and I am looking into iPads.
In Android knowing till when Google supports security/software upgrades is important when making a decision on what phone to buy.
Is this relevant for Apple too? I was Googling and it seems that it is expected that one can keep an iPad at best case for around 5 years but I don't understand exactly what that means?
E.g. if I look at a 2022 model does that mean that Apple will support security/software updates till 2027? Or that a 2022 model if I buy it today it will last me for 5 years? I.e. usable until 2029?

I’m voting to close this question because this iPad question is off-topic here and better suited for the Apple Stack Exchange site.

@Giacomo1968: I wasnt aware of that exchange. How can I migrate it? I have seen some people do such transfers but I don't see an option

@Giacomo1968: I think that penalizes though. How do users migrate various posts to other stackexhanges? Only admins or special users have that option?

Tried a search? idk if it's worth an answer, but https://discussions.apple.com/docs/DOC-250001726 Doesn't actually list support dates but get an idea from the ios version, 5 & 6 year old ones are still on 18.2 (current now?).

I don’t think you are penalized. If you want to migrate the actual post by other means, just flag it for “moderator intervention” yourself.

@Xen2050: I am confused with that page. I see iPad | Tenth| 10.9 | A14 Bionic | 2022 | 18.2 | Lightning | First Generation Apple Pencil via an adapter / New Apple Pencil (USB-C) | N/A | Currently Sold for instance. It mentions 18.2 but when I check devices sold they either mention IPadOS 16 or just IPadOS. Is this the same thing?

That list is unofficial. It is just a post by an average user on Apple’s support site.

As a general rule, when you buy a brand new device (newly released) from Apple you can usually assume it will work/be support for at least 5 years, you can also assume after 10 years it will no longer be supported and there will be software you can't install as a result of that. At the 7/8 year mark I would be ready to buy something new as its quite likely you will have an issue soon.

@DavidT: So if you buy a brand new does that mean that after 5 years there is no support for security upgrades? E.g. 0 day vulnerabilities and other issues are not patched so it all depends on the usage for security safety?
